# How to do the value binding in datatable when selection mode = multiple

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need explanation for the below value binding in the outputText inside  p:dialog .I dont clear with that and is there any other way.

In my sample :
I have tried ,if i select the single or many check box the value get binded but when I click root check box which used for selecting all the check boxes, its getting selected but the values not get stored in the back end.

```
<p:dataTable id="checkboxDT" 
             var="car" 
             value="#{dtSelectionView.cars6}" 
             selection="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCars}" 
             rowKey="#{car.id}" 
             style="margin-bottom:0">
    <f:facet name="header">
        Checkbox
    </f:facet>
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" 
              style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Year">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Brand">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Color">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
    </p:column>
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton process="checkboxDT" 
                         update=":form:multiCarDetail" 
                         icon="ui-icon-search" 
                         value="View" 
                         oncomplete="PF('multiCarDialog').show()" />
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>



<p:dialog header="Selected Cars" 
          widgetVar="multiCarDialog" 
          modal="true" 
          showEffect="fade" 
          hideEffect="fade" 
          resizable="false" 
          width="200">
    <p:outputPanel id="multiCarDetail" style="text-align:center;">
        <ui:repeat value="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCars}" 
                   var="car">

            <h:outputText value="#{car.id} - #{car.brand}" 
                          style="display:block"/>
        </ui:repeat>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: <h:outputText value="#{car.id} - #{car.brand}" 
                          style="display:block"/>

Answer (score 1):

You should update checkboxDT because update is used to determines id’s of components to be updated (refreshed with updated values from server). If you do not update checkboxDT, the selectedCars do not update too.

```
<p:commandButton process="checkboxDT" 
                 update="checkboxDT,:form:multiCarDetail" 
                 icon="ui-icon-search" 
                 value="View" 
                 oncomplete="PF('multiCarDialog').show()" />
```

Comment: <h:outputText value="#{car.id} - #{car.brand}" 
                          style="display:block"/> can you explain value binding they given in value="#{car.id} - #{car.brand}" .In my sample project am able to get only first value i.e (car.id ) only .

Comment: Have you check brand value in selectedCars list?

Comment: can we use p:ajax rowselect event for datatable  when we given the selection mode is multiple

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: p:ajax rowSelectCheckbox event is not working in column header check box

Comment: How it not working? Please post in new question and show your code.

Comment: i have asked other question as u say the question is "p:ajax rowSelectCheckbox event is not working in column header check box" and  i have attached the code also.pls refer.